# Web server for testing POST requests

Tags: post, testing, webserver

I am developing part of an application which will POST requests to another server, and examine the request as the web server would see it.

Is there any web server that I can set up (quickly and easily) that will allow me to view the requests to it, and return a sensible code. It doesn't need to process the data in any way. It basically just for development / testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST-client tool to observe the performance.

Comment: This seems to be a client that sends web requests. I am looking for a web server that receives the requests, and allows me to view them (and return a dummy response). (Maybe this does that also, but it is not clear, and the documentation seems non existent).